# Intersecting a function and its inverse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

I was wondering is there any quicker way to solve find a function and its inverse's points of intersection without bashing it up with algebra?

For instance, I've observed that if a function is strictly increasing, then any points of intersection it has with its inverse must lie on $y=x$.

However, I've also observed that in some functions, the points of intersections it has with its inverse can lie on $y=-x$.

Is there any particular reason why it lies on $y=-x$ or is it a coincidence?

Some examples I can give: $-x^3$, and $4-2\sqrt{2x+6}$.

Essentially what I'm trying to ask, is before I attempt to solve a question that asks to find the intersection between the function and it's inverse, what are somethings I should consider? If it's not strictly increasing do I sadly just have to bash it up with algebra?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127722/discussion-on-question-by-allan-lakosh-intersecting-a-function-and-its-inverse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphically, transforming an invertible function $f$ to it's inverse $f^{-1}$ reflects the graph of $f$ over the line $y=x$. Now, we note that a function $f$ is invertible if and only if it is continuous and strictly monotone.

Now, if $f$ is strictly increasing, then $a<b \iff f(a)<f(b)$ (by definition).

Now consider $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}(b)$.

If $f^{-1}(a)<f^{-1}(b)$, the by $f$ strictly increasing we have $$f^{-1}(a)<f^{-1}(b)\iff f(f^{-1}(a))<f(f^{-1}(b))$$but the righthand side simplifies to $a<b$ by the inverse property $f(f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x.$ So we obtain (upon switching the order of the left and right sides of the $\iff$) $$a<b \iff f^{-1}(a)<f^{-1}(b)$$ which proves $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing (see how this matches the above definition of strictly increasing, but for $f^{-1}$?

A similar argument for strictly decreasing $f$ follows:
$f$ strictly decreasing means $$a<b \iff f(a)>f(b)$$

Now we instead pick on $f^{-1}(b)<f^{-1}(a)$ (you'll see why later in the argument).
We now use the fact that $f$ is strictly decreasing to conclude that $$f^{-1}(b)<f^{-1}(a)\iff f(f^{-1}(b))>f(f^{-1}(a))$$ and again the righthand side simplifies to $b>a$ which can be written instead as $a<b$. $$f^{-1}(b)<f^{-1}(a)\iff a<b$$ We swap $f^{-1}(b)<f^{-1}(a)$ to $f^{-1}(a)>f^{-1}(b)$ and again swap sides around $\iff$ and thus obtain $$a<b\iff f^{-1}(a)>f^{-1}(b)$$ and thus we have shown $f^{-1}$ is strictly decreasing.

Thus we have the following result:

Given an invertible real function $f$, if $f$ is strictly increasing, then so is $f^{-1}$, if instead $f$ is strictly decreasing, so is $f^{-1}$.

Note that for any invertible $f$ the points where $f(x)=x$ will provide an intersection point for the graphs and $f$ and $f^{-1}$. For an increasing $f$ such a point may not exist (if $f$ always trends above, or instead, always below the line $y=x$ no such points will exist). You can also have more than one such point, and in fact $f(x)=x$ *is* an invertible strictly increasing function where *all* of its points are intersections with $f^{-1}$. But are all intersection points between the graphs of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ of this form for strictly increasing $f$? Consider a point $(x,y)$ with $x<y$ (so this point is *above* the line $y=x$). Inversion maps this point to $(y,x)$ (which is *below* $y=x$). Moreover, in order for $f$ to intersect $f^{-1}$ at $(x,y)$ We must have that $f(x)=y=f^{-1}(x)$, in particular, $f^{-1}$ must *also* pass through this point. But if that is true, the we have $f^{-1}(x)=y$, and applying $f$ to both sides gives $f(f^{-1}(x))=f(y)$, so $f(y)=x$ ($f$ must *also* pass through $(y,x)$). These kinds of intersection points (not on the line $y=x$) occur in *pairs*, but now we have a problem. Any function that passes through both $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ must be *decreasing* as we have $f(x)=y$ and $f(y)=x$, so if $x<y$ then by substitution $f(y)<f(x)$ which is $f(x)>f(y)$. So we obtained $x<y \iff f(x)>f(y)$ which contradicts our assumption that $f$ was increasing.

So the points of the form $(x,x)$ are the *only* points that a strictly *increasing* invertible function $f$ can intersect with it's inverse.

This takes care of the increasing case, what about the decreasing case? In that case, points not on the line $y=x$ can do occur (and in pairs as shown above). I claim there is also *exactly one* point of the form $(x,x)$ that will work for a given decreasing $f$. The existence of the point is easy to see from the end behavior of $y=x$. This is because $y=x$ will eventually reach arbitrarily small values as $x$ decreases and arbitrarily large values as $x$ increases. That this point is unique can be deduced from the fact that $y=x$ is strictly increasing *and unbounded*, and that $f$ is strictly decreasing. We are guaranteed that $y=x$ will eventually cross the bound(s) if they exist and if there isn't one, then they must cross because of their end behavior. Moreover, once they do cross, it can never happen again because $y=x$ is increasing, but $f$ is decreasing. Hence, after they cross they continue to head in opposite directions and hence will never cross again.

There is a trick to finding the point(s) on the line. The point(s) means that $f(x)=x$, hence solving the equation $f(x)=x$ for $x$ for your given function will yield the possible points. Finding the pairs for decreasing $f$'s is a little trickier, but recall that in those cases, $f(x)=y$ and $f(y)=x$. By substitution of the first into the second, we obtain $f(f(x))=x$, which is the equation to solve to find the pairs of points (if any) for decreasing $f$ (note that it's possible for a function to have many pairs, even for the entire function to work as a solution; example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$)

Comment: Thank you so much for your beautifully presented explanation. I'm just wondering is there a trick with this function? $4-2\sqrt{2x+6}$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(x)=4-2\sqrt{2x+6}$ is decreasing, so my advice above for decreasing functions applies to it.